# TransactionSynchronizationManager sync execution after commit

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I was working with TransactionSynchronizationManager,was wondering if aftercommit executes in sync manner or async.

As I want to do some action after commit but dont want that to be async call

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `AbstractPlatformTransaction:803`, `triggerAfterCommit(status)` is a synchronous call to invoke all registered after commit synchronizations.